# Spring Boot Jersey static content with resources at "/"

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I have a project setup with Spring Boot and Jersey, and I need to serve static content. The main difference with other similar questions is the fact that "mywebsite.com/" has to be a Jersey resource. This is my current JerseyConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.mywebsite.services.rest",
                 "com.mywebsite.services.publication");

        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }
}
```

And my publication resource:

```
@Component
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class PublicacionResource {

        @GET
        public Template index() throws Throwable {
            return generateTemplateWithParameters("instalaciones", null, null);
        }

       ...
}
```

Jersey doesn't seem to be forwarding the 404 requests, as I cannot access static content.

Comment: Did you configure Jersey to run as a filter?

Comment: Yes, I set `spring.jersey.type=filter`

Comment: _"The main difference with other similar questions is the fact that "mywebsite.com/" has to be a Jersey resource."_ - Is this implying that without the `/` resource, it works?

Comment: Or is this a problem with accessing the MVC content? Static and MVC content are different stories

Comment: I meant that I need Jersey Resources at the root URL "/", and also need to serve static content. So other solutions I saw said to start the `@ApplicationStart` at /rest as a workaround, but this isn't an option in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an Exception in generateTemplateWithParameters and forward it via ExceptionMapper

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionProvider implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final MyException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it in Jersey's ResourceConfig:

```
register(MyExceptionProvider.class);
```